# MySQL update to SQL Server syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to "convert" this MYSQL query to SQL Server.

```
update folder_t  a, folder_t  b 
set a.datum_publikace=b.datum_publikace,
    a.datum_expirace=b.datum_expirace,a.nazev=b.nazev 
where a.link=b.idecko and b.linkTyp=0 and a.sekce=20
```

The current error I am getting:

> Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

It is obvious the problem lies in the syntax but really can not find the answer anywhere.

I am a novice when it comes to SQL Server.

If anyone can help out I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SQL Server UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) syntax:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.datum_publikace = b.datum_publikace,
    a.datum_expirace  = b.datum_expirace,
    a.nazev           = b.nazev 
FROM folder_t a
JOIN folder_t b 
  ON a.link = b.idecko
WHERE b.linkTyp = 0 
  AND a.sekce = 20;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot